# Is There a Settings Viewer/Manager for Windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, application-settings, roaming

For testing my roaming and/or local settings, I'd like to be able to clear all the settings.

I could do it like so, I guess:

```
App.roamingSettings.Value["SomeVal"] = string.Empty;
App.roamingSettings.Value["SomeOtherVal"] = string.Empty;
App.roamingSettings.Value["YetAnotherVal"] = string.Empty;
...
etc.
```

...but I'd rather have some quicker, cleaner (no pun intended) way. Is there one?

Also, relatedly, it would be nice to have a "Settings Manager" utility for quickly verifying they are what you think they are, too. Does anybody know of one?

### UPDATE

This is my attempt to "roll my own" based on the answer; so far, no go:

```
string roamingSettingPairs = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < App.roamingSettings.Values.Count; i++)
{
    // Print out whatever you want to verify that everything is as it should be
    //string roamingSettingName = App.roamingSettings.Name[i].ToString();
    //string roamingSettingValue = App.roamingSettings.Values[i].ToString();
    Dictionary<string, object> roamingSettingVals = App.roamingSettings.Values;
    string roamingSettingName = roamingSettingVals.Keys[i];
    object roamingSettingObj = roamingSettingVals.Values[i];
    //roamingSettingPairs = string.Format("{0}{1}={2}{3}", roamingSettingPairs, roamingSettingName,
      //                                  roamingSettingValue, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all of your roaming settings using this code:

```
ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.Clear();
```

For a Settings Manager, I would probably just use a for loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values.Count; i++)
{
    // Print out whatever you want to verify that everything is as it should be
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement the exercise left to the poster. I'm adding above to show what I've tried - getting all sorts of compiler errors so far no matter what I try.